# Infinite subset in compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Then $A$ contains a Cauchy sequence.

**My attempt:** Since $X$ is a metric space, then $X$ is a limit point compact. Then $A$ has a limit point, say $x$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ that converges in $A.$ Hence, $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands the conclusion is trivial: for a non-empty set we can always use a *constant* sequence with value in $A$.

The intended conclusion is more along the lines of

There is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ with all $a_n \in A$ so that *all terms are distinct* which is a Cauchy sequence.

For that we can indeed use the limit point compactness or ,even better, the sequential compactness of $X$.